# Recurring events library

Tags: java, android, events, calendar

I'm trying to implement an agenda function to my app, but until now I haven't found any library that can help me with this. I've read about the Calendar Provider and Google Calendar API but didn't find anything on their docs about creating events only for my app.

At the moment I've created a database to store my events with the following structure:

```
id - Integer used as primary key for the event;
user_id - Integer used to bound the user;
start_date - Date of the event;
end_date - Date with the end of the event's recurrence.
rec_sunday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on sunday.
rec_monday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on monday.
rec_tuesday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on tuesday.
rec_wednesday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on wednesday.
rec_thursday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on thursday.
rec_friday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on friday.
rec_saturday - Boolean if the event reoccurs on saturday.
recurrence - Boolean if the event has recurrence, so I won't need to check for all others booleans.
```

For now, I just need some logic to create the events in an ArrayList plus the recurring events, with their dates, so after that I can sort them with a Comparator using the date as base.

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque)'s amazing answer I'm now using the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library. It's an amazing library and it was much more easy to use than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [other Answer by Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414188/642706) may be the way to go, using iCal4j.

But to directly answer your Question…

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `DayOfWeek`

The [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum would be handy here.

[`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a special implementation of `Set` that uses bitmaps internally to represent a collection of enum elements in a *very* little amount of memory with *very* fast operations. The idea here is to use an `EnumSet` rather than your boolean-per-day-of-week approach. No need for the extra boolean about recurrence as you can just see if the `EnumSet` has any elements or not; no elements means no recurrence.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

By the way, in [standard date-handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), a week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. While you may not want to present a week that way to your users, I suggest sticking with the standard internally. This Monday-to-Sunday approach is the order defined in the `DayOfWeek` enum as well.

## Your class

Define a class for `Event`.

```
public class Event {
    Integer id ;
    Integer user_id ;
    LocalDate start , stop ;
    Set< DayOfWeek > recurrence ; 
}
```

You can initialize the `recurrence` EnumSet with an empty set if you wish.

```
recurrence = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class );
```

Then add items. You might do this with an `if` statement when retrieving data from database where if the SQL BOOLEAN column value of row is TRUE call the [`.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method here.

```
recurrence.add( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

Check size of set to see if this event is recurring.

```
Boolean isRecurring = ( recurrence.size() > 0 );
```

For sorting your objects, implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) by simply delegating to the `start` member’s `LocalDate` implementation. I do not recall exact syntax for generics with `Comparable`, but here is the rough idea.

```
public class Event implements Comparable {
    …
    @Override
    public int compareTo( Event otherEvent ) {
        return this.start.compareTo( otherEvent.start ) ;
    }
```

To fill a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of each occurrence, do something like this loop.

A [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) manipulates a date-time object to generate a new date-time object. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note plural) class provides implementations, including the one we need `next` and/or [`nextOrSame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-). The `start` might need to be included as an occurrence; I'll leave that finessing to the reader as an exercise. ;-)

```
if( recurrences.size > 0 ) { // If any recurrences to schedule…
    List<LocalDate> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate ld = this.start ;
    while ( ld.isBefore( this.stop ) ) {
        for( DayOfWeek dow , this.recurrence ) {
            ld = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( dow ) );
            occurrences.add( ld );
…
```

Note the logic in the code above where we test for each date being *before* the stop date, *not* less-than-or-equal-to. This Half-Open approach is common in date-time work, where a span of time is defined with the beginning as *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

You may want to sanity-check the span of time between your start and stop. If an error was made resulting in an absurdly long gap, you could blow out memory with a huge `List` of occurrences. The [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class helps for this check.

```
if ( Period.between( start , stop ).getYears() > 10 )  {   // If over a decade, halt. 
…
```

Caveat: All the code above is untested and never run. Just off the top of my head. Hopefully enough to get you started.

For scheduling, consider the [*Quartz Job Scheduler*](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but unfortunately I can't use Java 8 as my project runs on API 16+ devices. Anyway your answer give me a good start point, so I've searched a little and finished using the Joda Time Library (and according to research a big part of the java.time is based on the Joda Time). So basically I'm selecting the events in my database based on the start and end date, then I'm looping through them, checking if they recur and creating the extra instances based on the recurrence rule that they have. Thank you for you answer!

Comment: [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) that defines java.time is lead by [Stephen Colbourne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), the same man who invented [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and led its development. Colbourne and the Joda-Time team now advises migration to java.time. Joda-Time is actively maintained but will not receive further major development efforts.

Comment: Sry, I've skipped through that part, and thank you, I'm using the ThreeTenABP, solved all the issues and works like a cham!

Comment: @BasilBourque I work for Android and I have created custom Calendar but no idea how can I manage Recurring events in the custom calendar, Have you any idea of recurring lib for android, I searched a lot but i didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using iCal4j? It's available on Maven Central and allows saving/reading calendar from a file on the file system. The added benefit of using something based on standards is if in the future you want to sync to other calendars/calendar providers it will be (in theory) easier to accomplish.

[iCal4j GitHub](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j)